# Readin a two-dimensional array using scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Suppose I have a txt file named "input.txt" and I want to use scala to read it in. The dimension of the file is not available in the beginning.

So, how to construct such an Array[Array[Float]]? What I want is a simple and neat way rather than write some code like in Java to iterates over lines and parse each number. I think functional programming should be quite good at it.. but cannot think of one up to now.

Best Regards

Comment: Are you sure that you want an Array? It is not needed if all you want is to iterate on it, and better structure, like iterators, may be better suited depending of your use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input is correct, you can do it in such way:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("input.txt")
val data = source.getLines().map(line => line.split(" ").map(_.toFloat)).toArray
source.close()
```

**Update**: for additional information about using `Source` check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/scala-user/io.Source.fromFile/scala-user/QZ6oje6hSHo/xELVmjBkhaQJ)

Comment: Note that this will leave a file descriptor open.